# In a query with joinned tables, how to set a where clause affecting only one line and not all the lines created by the joining

Tags: mysql, sql

I built a web app with php and a mysql database. Users can suggest ideas or make requests, and the site managers can validate it. If all the managers validated the request, it's accepted.

I have 4 tables in my database, one for the users, one for the user's requests, one for the managers, and one for the manager's validations flow.

```
User
______
Id PK
Name
...

User_s_request
______________
Id PK
User_id
Request

Manager
_________
User_id PK

Manager_s_validation
____________________
User_request_id PK
Manager_id PK
Validation_date
```

When a manager goes to the validation page, I display an html table showing the user's requests that still need the validation of this manager.

```
SELECT ur.id from user_request AS ur
JOIN manager_validation AS mv ON mv.user_request_id = ur.id
JOIN manager AS m ON m.user_id = mv.manager_id
WHERE mv.manager_id != $manager_id OR mv.user_request_id IS NULL
LIMIT 1
```

My query works when this manager did not validated yet. The request is displayed. My query works when the only validation is from this manager.
But it doesn't work if this manager and another one (or more) validated. The request is displayed, when it should not be.

How could be the right request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to @sticky bit, here it is:

```
SELECT *
   FROM user_request ur
   WHERE ur.id NOT IN 
       // I select the ids of the validated requests (by this manager)
       (SELECT mv.user_request_id
       FROM manager_validation mv
       WHERE mv.manager_id = ?);
// the users_s_request may be displayed several times (for each validation by a manager)
// so I limit the result to 1 only
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are searching for `NOT EXISTS`, i.e. select all user requests for which no validation exists for a certain manager.

```
SELECT *
       FROM user_request ur
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM manager_validation mv
                                WHERE mv.user_request_id = ur.id
                                      AND mv.manager_id = ?);
```

Comment: The request is not displayed anymore for this manager, good point. But it's not displayed for any other manager who has to validate. Problem not solved. But you gave me a way to solve (I'll answer to my question to show the solution), so thanks !